# Decrypt values with the same key at different levels from base64

Tags: json, base64, jq

My input is like below. I want to search for `SearchString` key (you can see that we can't use a fixed index for it) and when the key appears decrypt its value from base64 (perhaps using `@base64d` filter). Is this possible with JQ? If so, how?

```
[
  {
    "Name": "searchblock",
    "Priority": 3,
    "Statement": {
      "RateBasedStatement": {
        "Limit": 100,
        "AggregateKeyType": "IP",
        "ScopeDownStatement": {
          "ByteMatchStatement": {
            "SearchString": "Y2F0YWxvZ3NlYXJjaA==",
            "FieldToMatch": {
              "UriPath": {}
            },
            "TextTransformations": [
              {
                "Priority": 0,
                "Type": "LOWERCASE"
              }
            ],
            "PositionalConstraint": "CONTAINS"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Action": {
      "Block": {}
    },
    "VisibilityConfig": {
      "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
      "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
      "MetricName": "searchblock"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "bot-block",
    "Priority": 4,
    "Statement": {
      "ByteMatchStatement": {
        "SearchString": "Ym90",
        "FieldToMatch": {
          "SingleHeader": {
            "Name": "user-agent"
          }
        },
        "TextTransformations": [
          {
            "Priority": 0,
            "Type": "LOWERCASE"
          }
        ],
        "PositionalConstraint": "CONTAINS"
      }
    },
    "Action": {
      "Allow": {}
    },
    "VisibilityConfig": {
      "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
      "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
      "MetricName": "user-agent"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `path`, `paths`, `getpath`, and `setpath` built-ins for such operations when a fixed path is not available.

```
getpath(paths | select(.[-1] == "SearchString")) |= @base64d
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1eY025eo0b)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your valuable time,it is working fine in my local system (jq version 1.6).but it returns an error  in my server "jq: error (at my.json:253): Invalid path expression with result "ZnJlc"(jq version 1.5) ,

Comment: check your jq version before using it. is only working with 1.6

Comment: I upgraded jq version and worked well, the other answer only returned the same input JSON. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

`walk` is quite intuitive for this kind of task:

```
walk(if type == "object" and .SearchString 
     then .SearchString |= @base64d else . end)
```

Using this approach, it's also trivial to modify the program to make it more robust, e.g. to check that .SearchString is a string:

```
walk(if type == "object" and (.SearchString|type) == "string" 
     then .SearchString |= @base64d else . end)
```

---

Note: if your jq does not include `walk`, you can simply copy its `def` from any reputable web site, or from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: The output is same as input json no change.